# What happens if I upvote or edit a post in my review queue, but not from there?

Tags: support, review

If I stumble upon a post that is in my review queue, and I upvote/downvote it, edit it, or whatever would cause it to be marked as reviewed when reviewing, does it count as reviewed towards the new badges?

or only when you interact from that dashboard does the post count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interact with it (and click "I'm Done") from the review page. If you interact with it independantly *before* you see it in the review page, you will need to interact with it again to enable the "I'm Done" button. Similarly, if you encounter it in the review page, go to the actual post, interact with it directly, and return to the review page for it, the "I'm Done" button *will not* be active, and you will need to do something else to the post to get it to count as reviewed.

Comment: This is basically correct. (*Source: I implemented it.*) A couple notes: if you've already interacted with a post, we try not to give it to you in the review queue. Also, if you click through to a post from review and interact with it, you can then refresh the review page to enable the "I'm Done" button.

Comment: Did not know refreshing the page enabled the "I'm Done" button! Thanks!